# Study the convergence of the sequence $u_n = 5 - \frac{8}{5}n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification

I would like to know if my thought on this problem are good. We have to study the convergence of the sequence $u_n = 5 - \frac{8}{5}n$. Intuitively it is clear that this sequence is not convergent in $\mathbb{R}$ and this is what I want to prove. Here is my idea : show that for an artificial limit point in $\mathbb{R}$, we can always go as far as we want to this point in some sense.

Suppose that $u_n$ converge to $l\in\mathbb{R}$. This means that

$$
\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N} : n> N\implies\lvert u_n - l\rvert < \epsilon
$$

Take $\epsilon = 1$, then there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N\implies\lvert u_n - l\rvert <1$. Now consider the distance between $u_n$ and $u_{n+2}$

$$
\lvert u_{n+2} - u_n\rvert = \left\lvert 5-\frac{8}{5}n - \left(5-\frac{8}{5}n -\frac{16}{5}\right)\right\rvert = \frac{16}{5}
$$

It follows that

$$
\lvert u_{n+2} - l\rvert = \lvert u_{n+2} - u_{n} + u_n - l\rvert\geq\lvert\lvert u_{n+2} - u_{n}\rvert - \lvert u_n - l\rvert \rvert> \left\lvert\frac{16}{5} - 1\right\rvert>\frac{11}{5}> 1
$$

which contradicts the convergence of $u_n$ to $l$.

Is this proof correct and have you other idea to prove this which use others concepts ? Clearly my idea is from the notion of Cauchy sequence.

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Your proof is correct. A simpler one would be: if $u_n\to l\in\Bbb R$ then $u_{n+1}-u_n\to l-l=0,$ which is absurd since $u_{n+1}-u_n=-\frac85.$ Alternatively: $(u_n)$ diverges to $-\infty,$ or simply: is not bounded (every convergent sequence is bounded).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for your these two methods, there was much more fulgurant indeed!

Comment: You can also just use the direct definition that it diverges to $-\infty$ : $\forall A \in\mathbb{R}\quad\exists N \in\mathbb{N}\quad\forall n \in\mathbb{N}\quad(n \geqslant N\Rightarrow u_n < A)$

Comment: @Lelouch Yes in the same line as proposed by Anne, thank you !